# Why do you have to access struct members with an '->'?

Tags: c, struct

Normally you access structure-members by a dot (`Struct.Member`), but when `Struct` is a pointer, you have to use `Struct->Member`

Is there a special reason for this? Because in both instances you're just referring to a piece of memory. And the compiler should be able to handle both operators, so is it just an enforced codestyle ?

Comment: You could use "(*Struct).Member".  It's just a way of dereferencing.  But in particular, it is a way of being specific about which level of dereferencing you are applying.

Comment: It's the same with the dereference operator `*`, why should you use that? The compiler should know that anyway? At least *modern* compilers.

Comment: It is just an extra operator to help deal with the quirky operator associativity rules in C.  You don't need it, but nobody thinks it is unnecessary.  It certainly makes pointer usage syntax more obvious, -> is pointy.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is hypothetical.


Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's because the language is defined that way.

There are languages that allow the prefix of the `.` operator to be either a structure or a pointer to a structure. No ambiguity is introduced because, as you say, the compiler knows what type the prefix is.

C just happens not to do that. I don't think there's any deep reason for it, it's just the way Dennis Ritchie decided to do it.

And using `.` for structures and `->` for pointers also makes it clear *to the reader* whether the prefix is a pointer or not. For a relatively low-level language like C, that kind of detail can be important.

Answer (score 0):

You can access the struct elements in `.` notation if the struct is a pointer. You just have to dereference the struct elements

So :

`(*struct).element` should work fine